# Do I need to use finings again after restarting the fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, wine, finings

I recently made a batch of red wine but because the wine was too sweet I restarted the fermentation as I was advised. Of course I will need to de-gas the wine again, do I also need to use finings again to clear the wine?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a crystal clear finish then unfortunately you will have to add more finings and rack again.